# How can I prevent mobile home door from swinging in the wind?

Tags: doors, trailer

I live in a travel trailer. It is really a home. I have frequent high winds. Is there a way to prevent my door from flying one way or the other?

[image]

Comment: A screen door closer is like a shock absorber with a lock on it to keep closing, if you want it open.

Comment: @crip659 Thanks for the input. I am thinking a bungee cord might be a better solution. It would slow down the swing of the door in high winds.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because repairing a trailer isn't Home Improvement per the [help].

Comment: I found an answer. But I can not post it because someone thinks it is off topic. It is NOT. My home is a travel trailer. I kindly suggest that some folks spend more time helping people instead of looking for ways to not help people.

Comment: [I agree](https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1642/35141) and have voted to reopen. I don't recall my specific close vote reason, but it may have been because this originally seemed like a shopping question. To be fair, I spend slightly more time helping than looking for reasons to close. It's close, but it's true.

Comment: A bungee stiff enough to stop wind slap would make usage of the door difficult. It'll also create a safety hazard with the return swing. It's not a good solution.

Comment: Are you wanting the door to stay fully open? Can you provide a picture of the stairs?  You might be able to make a quick and dirty door stop mounted to the stairs that pins the door open and won't allow it to move.

Comment: Voted to reopen as I think it is a valid question.

Comment: Closing the door is one option.

Answer (score 1):

I found a place where the door can be latched onto the trailer.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use a "cabin hook" to latch it open when you want it to stay open.  Attach the hook to a suitable railing or post, and the eye to the door.